# can ping a unix server but cant putty from a specific network provider connection

Tags: linux, putty, ping

I have a Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client and am able to connect to the client network successfully. Once connected, i am able to putty to a unix server without any issues. However puttying to a unix server works only when am using the internet connection from a specific provider(say airtel). If i try to putty to the unix server when i switch my provider to (say BSNL) then am not able to putty to the server. In both cases am able to ping the server though. Any idea what could be the reason? Is it some settings in my pc which is causing this erratic behavior?

Comment: Are you talking about SSH?  If so, please specify (preferably by using that as the verb, and PuTTY as the implementation).  Does OpenSSH also have the same issue?  What does `traceroute` tell you?  Are you sure the SSH (or other) traffic is going out on the same network interface as ping?

Comment: Basically my intention is simple: Use cisco anyconnect using the client supplied credentials to  connect to the client network. Once connected I need to access a linux server for app deployments. My problem is that I am able to connect to this linux server using putty only when am using connection from a specific internet provider. So I doubt whether somesetting in my pc is preventing me to access the linux server when am using a specific internet provider. How can i troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Be more specific. What error do you get? You can't expect anyone to understand your question you don't get sufficient information. Also try telnetting to port 22 and report here.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not getting any error but the putty window remains blank forever.  
I am trying to see whether I can get some logs for putty.  
In the meantime i tried telnet to the port 22 after connecting using my internet connection provider BSNL and am getting the following  
**SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8**  
**Connection to host lost**  
Let me try telnetting using my alternate internet connection provider and post the output here.

Comment: When i switched my connection provider to say airtel and after connecting using the cisco anyconnect, i tried telnetting to the port 22. It prints the line **SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8** and remains like that for around 2 minutes and then prints  **Connection to host lost**. However am able to putty successfully.. Feeling strange.. :-(

Comment: It is OK for TELNET to remain blank and timeout, since you cannot emulate the binary stream used by SSH. The UNIX machine waits for input which it never get and then time out.

Comment: Can you ssh to other servers with Cisco-VPN with the problematic provider.

Comment: @user3767013 How can I check whether access restrictions exists in the SSH server? Could you kindly advise? Also what exactly you mean by 'Different ISP use different IP ranges' .. Am a big zero in terms of network connectivity terms and theories.. :-(

Comment: @user3767013 Unfortunately I am not aware whether any other servers exists as the client has only given instruction to access this machine,

Comment: I withdrew my comment about access restrictions after noticed you are  using vpn. With vpn you will always get ip addresses from the vpn access point, so the original ip from ISP will not be seen by the UNIX server, making it irrelevant. You do not need to check in this area.

Comment: Can you use vpn to access any thing other than this one ssh over the problematic provider? If no, vpn has just established the connection but cannot transfer data. If yes, the vpn is working. Also please use "ipconfig /all" to find out if you get same IP address from vpn over different providers.

Comment: @user3767013 Am able to access FTP residing in the same server using the problematic provider. However am not able to even access the deployed webapplications via browser while using the problematic provider.

Comment: @user3767013 Yes I inspected my machines IP and it is different when connected using the problematic provider. one additional observation is that I tried connecting using two other different internet provider and in both those instances the ip where same and i was able to access the server via putty as well.. so how can i fix my ip when connected using the problematic provider?

Comment: @user3767013 Interestingly when i tried again connecting via the porblematic provider, i received the same IP as the one which was obtained using two other providers. But this time am not able to putty to the server. So can we rule out the  IP address issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like either something is interrupting the connection on BSNL.  Another possibility would be TCP Windowing and packet sizes.

You can test the size difference with PING in a command line and also with the "don't fragment" flag set

open a command prompt type:   ping /?

it should print a list of switches.  On windows 10 its showing me -l (lower case L) is for size and -f for "don't fragment"

Start with 1420
ping -f -l 1420

with your remote server host name or ip after the 1420.  If both fail, back it off to 1380 .. if both pass, increase by 5 .. like 1425 ... 1430 etc.. until you start getting a failure.

A good test would be regardless of connection, try to ping google's DNS server with "ping -f -l 1300 8.8.8.8"

At home on comcast ... I'm getting 1272 with "dont fragment" as a working value, and 1273 I get "packet needs to be fragmented but DF set"

So if you see significantly less from one ISP to the other, your problem is most likely that.

FYI, TPLink has a good page demonstrating the above, and also notes that this is a common problem with VPN connections.
http://www.tp-link.us/FAQ-190.html

You would manually set the MTU for *that* VPN connector/connection. It would probably effect both (since its the same cisco client) so you'd have to go with the lower value that allows both to work.

Rough example of commands to change MTU here
https://support.zen.co.uk/kb/Knowledgebase/Changing-the-MTU-size-in-Windows-Vista-7-or-8
you'll probably have to play with the commands a little or re-google with your specific windows version.

Comment: Excellent dude....You saved my day!!!!.. I figured out the correct optimum MTU setting by referring the links you have shared and yes it worked great!!... thanks a ton!!..